# Creating a DbGeography describing a rectangle

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, spatial

I have a two points describing a rectangle: 
a Northeast Lat/Long and a Southwest Lat/Long.

What will be the correct and efficient way to generate a simple rectangle entity that can be stored in a `DbGeography` field?

Note that later on I would like to use that field to determine if a POINT is inside this Rectangle.

I realize I should use `DbGeography.FromText(...)` methods, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `FromText` method expects a [WKT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) representation, in this case for a polygon:

Something like this should do the trick:

```
DbGeography box = DbGeography.FromText(
    string.Format("POLYGON(({0} {1}, {0} {2}, {3} {2}, {3} {1}, {0} {1}))",
                         nwLongitude, 
                         nwLatitude,
                         seLatitude,
                         seLongitude), 4326);
```

Comment: Do you really need to call `ToString()` if you're passing to `string.Format()` anyway?

Comment: Does it matter that the question is based in NorthEast/SouthWest where as the answer is NorthWest/SouthEast? The ordering of the values stays the same? WHen I try it the orientation of the box is sideways and upsidedown.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have the NE and SW coordinates , you can use this :

```
DbGeography box = DbGeography.FromText(
        string.Format("POLYGON(({0} {1}, {0} {2}, {3} {2}, {3} {1}, {0} {1}))",
                             swLongitude,  //nwLongitude, 
                             neLatitude, //nwLatitude,
                             swLatitude, //seLatitude,
                             neLongitude, //seLongitude
    ), 4326);
```